# Mutate multiple cumsum in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I am trying to develop a cumsum with `mutate`. The challenge is that I have 10 columns to do and I know how to do one by one. Is there a way where I can do something like `mutate(across(all_of(c(3:4)), ~cumsum(c(3:4)))`?

```
cat %>% 
  group_by(animals) %>%
  mutate(weight1 = cumsum(weight1),
         weight2 = cumsum(weight2))
```

```
structure(list(animals = c("E1", "E1", "E1", 
"E2", "E2", "E2"), period = structure(c(18690, 
18697, 18704, 18690, 18697, 18704), class = "Date"), weight1 = c(704, 
734, 653, 851, 911, 829), weight2 = c(0, 235, 325, 0, 148, 
200)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Expected output:

```
  animals period     weight1 weight2
  <chr>   <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1 E1      2021-03-04     704       0
2 E1      2021-03-11    1438     235
3 E1      2021-03-18    2091     560
4 E2      2021-03-04     851       0
5 E2      2021-03-11    1762     148
6 E2      2021-03-18    2591     348
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to do this

```r
df <- structure(list(animals = c("E1", "E1", "E1", 
                           "E2", "E2", "E2"), period = structure(c(18690, 
                                                                   18697, 18704, 18690, 18697, 18704), class = "Date"), weight1 = c(704, 
                                                                                                                                    734, 653, 851, 911, 829), weight2 = c(0, 235, 325, 0, 148, 
                                                                                                                                                                          200)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")) 

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(animals) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("weight"), cumsum))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   animals [2]
#>   animals period     weight1 weight2
#>   <chr>   <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 E1      2021-03-04     704       0
#> 2 E1      2021-03-11    1438     235
#> 3 E1      2021-03-18    2091     560
#> 4 E2      2021-03-04     851       0
#> 5 E2      2021-03-11    1762     148
#> 6 E2      2021-03-18    2591     348
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**or**

`vars <- names(df)[3:4]`

`df %>%  group_by(animals) %>% mutate(across(all_of(vars), cumsum))`

Comment: Thanks and I like the `all_of` approach.

Answer (score 2):

You will get an error with what you are trying to do. Once you `group_by(animals)`, there are only three columns that `mutate` can operate on. So you could use:

```
cat %>% 
  group_by(animals) %>%
  mutate(across(2:3, cumsum))
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   animals [2]
  animals period     weight1 weight2
  <chr>   <date>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1 E1      2021-03-04     704       0
2 E1      2021-03-11    1438     235
3 E1      2021-03-18    2091     560
4 E2      2021-03-04     851       0
5 E2      2021-03-11    1762     148
6 E2      2021-03-18    2591     348
```

But this approach requires you to know what the new indices would be. Better to try something programmatically. If all the columns are weights, you could use:

```
cat %>% 
  group_by(animals) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("weight"), cumsum))
```

Or if you just want to operate on all numeric columns:

```
cat %>% 
  group_by(animals) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), cumsum))
```

Both of the latter two approaches give your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution:

```
num_col_idx <- vapply(df, is.numeric, logical(1))

cbind(df[,!num_col_idx],
      data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(
        split(df[, num_col_idx], df$animals), cumsum)), row.names = NULL))
```